# Should I delete question that is an open problem and has been discussed in papers?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, deletion

Related question:[Finding $\max |A|$ with $a_{ij}=\pm 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2911674)
I have asked this question before I searched OEIS. After I have asked this question, I found this problem called "Hadamard maximal determinant problem". This question is an open problem and there are some papers about it.
I doubt that this question can make a contribution to Math.SE. If this problem can't contribute to this site, should I delete this question?

Comment: If the problem is open BUT (interesting to general public AND not very famous), an answer which summarize the current status will be a good addition to math.SE. If the problem is not "interesting" or very famous, then deleting the question seems to be the right choice.

Comment: Until your Question has an upvoted or Accepted Answer, it is allowed for you to delete your own Question.  That said, such a Question might well be of interest to future Readers and could well be addressed with summaries of what is known about the problem.  I'd certainly rather have such a summary response than have the Question deleted, but that's my preference.  It's up to you at this point.

Comment: The problem is open, and is interesting. I would rate it as quite famous, but not nearly as famous as, say, the Riemann Hypothesis, or the $3x+1$ problem. I'd like to encourage OP to write up a summary response, and post it as an answer (but maybe check first to see whether it's a duplicate – a search for Hadamard determinant should turn up any earlier instances of the question).

Comment: I found a almost same question on MO.

Comment: Props for asking here. Seconding Gerry Myerson's above suggestion. FWIW I added a link to Neil Sloane's page on Hadamard matrices in a comment.

Comment: @The, why are you bumping all these questions?

Comment: I agree this is a useful type of question even if the correct answer turned out to be "that is an open problem". I have posted a CW answer documenting the known answer.